# Continue receiving data from Arduino after disconnect

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, arduino-uno

I made a dashboard where light input from a lightsensor on a Arduino uno is converted to a percentage. I am trying to continue receiving input after my Arduino is disconnected.

```
try:
    ser = Serial(
        port='COM3',
        baudrate=19200,
        parity=PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=0)
except:
    print("Disconnected")

def updateTick():
    try:
        f.root.after(1000, updateTick)
        value = ser.read()
        min = 25                #min light value
        max = 50                #max light value
        if value:
            lightNum = int.from_bytes(value, byteorder='little')
            print(lightNum)
            lightToPercentage = round((lightNum - min) * 100 / (max - min))
            #print(lightToPercentage)
            view.l1.lightLabelCount.config(text="{}%".format(lightToPercentage))
            checkPreset(lightToPercentage)
            updateGraph(lightToPercentage)
    except:
        view.l1.lightLabelCount.config(text="N/A")
        view.l1.lightLabelPreset.config(text="[Restart]")
```

So, when i start the dashboard, I receive data from my Arduino, when I disconnect my arduino, the percentage in de dashboard changes to N/A.

But what I am trying to do is to receive data again as soon as the Arduino is connected again.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to express pseudo code of the possible solution came up my mind. It may help somehow.

```
if(check if serial comm. exist)
   read received value
   write the value to dashboard
else
   write last received value to dashboard
   while(!(check if serial comm. exist))
      keep writing last received value to dashboard
//when comm. come back, it'll automaticly update the value
```